# Does Anyone Use FileMaker Pro to Build iPhone Apps?

Tags: objective-c, swift, filemaker

My company has an app built using FileMaker Pro, and it is not a great app. It's not user friendly and it is hard to use. It also doesn't do everything that we need it to do. I don't know anything about Filemaker Pro, but it seems like it's an older system. Most people building iPhone apps are coding in objective C and swift right?

Does anyone have any input on Filemaker Pro? Anything you share would help. Is it old? Does it have a lot of limitations? Is it popular to use when building apps? Does anyone still use it or are most apps built in Objective C and Swift with a text editor?

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 4):

Your question is really off-topic for StackOverflow, but I will provide a couple of pointers:

1. [FileMaker](http://www.filemaker.com/) is not old - it's very current.
2. FileMaker is **not** a tool for building iOS apps. FileMaker is a tool (or set of tools) for developing and deploying cross-platform database solutions. One of these tools is [FileMaker Go](http://www.filemaker.com/products/filemaker-go/) - an iOS app that will run a solution developed in FileMaker. This appears to the user as a native iOS app.
3. If the solution does not fit your needs, the fault is more likely to lie with the developer than with the platform.
4. If you're not running FileMaker as part of your business, then FileMaker Go is probably not the best choice for you.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for the reply. I appreciate it!